# nodejs how to fix DRY issue caused by putting routes.js in a folder

Tags: node.js, express, path, routes

[My file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzezz.png) - note that routes.js is located inside the controllers:

Before I would simply write `public` or `views`

```
   app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
        .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))`
```

But now, since I nested the `route.js` file in a folder, I am forced to go up a directory before being able to point to the e.g. `public` folder.

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const appRouter = function(app, chatDB) {

    //static files
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')))
            .set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'))
            .set('view engine', 'pug');
};
module.exports = appRouter;
```

**Question**

Is it possible to avoid having to prepend `../` each time? (for DRY purposes)